Regularity of Metric when defining C^k norms
Given $(M^n, g)$ closed riemannian manifold, I am wondering about the definition of the $C^k$ norms with respect to the metric, and how these norms depend on $g$. For example, I would assume that if $x$ is a local coordinate on $M$, then for $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$, we can define
$$f'(x) = \lim_{y \to x} \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{\text{dist}_g(x,y)}$$
and
$$||f||_{C^1,g} = \text{sup}_{x \in M} |f(x)| + \text{sup}_{x \in M} |f'(x)|$$
Now a priori, if the first equation is the correct definition for $f'(x)$, then it may be that higher derivatives of $f$ depend on derivatives of $g$ a priori. This raises the question of how does $||f||_{C^k, g}$ depend on the regularity of $g$?
In addition, if we use exponential map coordinates to define $f'(x)$, does the regularity of $g$ affect the smoothness of these coordinates? And hence the $|| \cdot ||_{C^k, g}$ norm as well?

That is not how I would define $f'$. By contrast, if $M = \Bbb R^n$ and I assume $f(0) = 0$, you're attempting to define $f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/|x|$. This will usually not be defined. Better is the gradient, defined by $g(\nabla f, v) = (df)(v)$, and then $|f|{C^1} = |f|{C^0} + |g(\nabla f, \nabla f)|_{C^0}$. This norm varies continuously as $g$ varies continuously in $C^0$.

Sure, do you have reference for that definition? I've definitely seen holder norms as
$$||f||{C^{\alpha}, g} = \sup{x \neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{dist_g(x,y)^{\alpha}}$$
So I'm extrapolating from that
